# How does SOQL work when mentioning something like "URL" instead of the object's API name?

Tags: apex, soql

I found this query in Apex class. It works and returns a list of Case records along with the related Case comments. The comments come from the query in round brackets. Can someone explain how SOQL works when the object is mentioned in this kind of format? Guessing, the numbers after the `salesforce_com` part mean Id of the object in Salesforce.

```
[SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM https_na23_salesforce_com_50063000003w__r) FROM Case]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a child relationship o case.
I'm guessing after this, you have a for or something like this?

```
SOMETHING_HERE = myCaseList[0].https_na23_salesforce_com_50063000003w__r
```

Am I correct?

You can use this to identify the object:

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult R = Case.SObjectType.getDescribe();
List<Schema.ChildRelationship> C = R.getChildRelationships();
System.debug('===\n===\n===\n' + JSON.serializePretty(C) + '===\n===\n===\n');
```

source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Schema_ChildRelationship.htm

Comment: You're right. Apparently, the query I found queries records from the relationship. Thanks!